# There is a pip error in Storm-Breaker when i use it on Virtual box

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm attempting to install Storm-Breaker by using ./install.sh but it gives me an error saying:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: './requirements.txt'
Hint: It looks like a path. The path does exist. The argument you provided (./requirements.txt) appears to be a requirements file. If that is the case, use the '-r' flag to install the packages specified within it.                                                                                                        
An error occurred! seems the pip doesn't work.
```

I have no idea what to do, can someone please help?
I'm new to this, and I tried the -r function but I'm not sure whether I used it correctly. But the same result came up again and again

Comment: Well. There are several [issue reports](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+requirement).

Comment: I didn't install the repo but if I were you I would try this [previous commit](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/commit/01e82438b13b687e60e15829297bbaffc064fff0) in [git logs](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/commits/main). The issue link's issues happend after [the commit](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/commit/a7ab1485e4cbbf23e40d77b033d742efd11cbbcb).

Comment: BTW I found the error point. I will do PR.

Comment: @ConstantinHong The solution is (as I believe) `python3 -m pip install --break-system-packages -r ./requirements.txt`

Comment: @phd Yes, you're right. It turns out that what I initially thought was a mistake originated from sleepiness.